Do I really need a Graph API access token for Meta Business Suite catalogue? If not, how does it work for a person access the catalogue?
Graph API access token on MBS is required to have access to the catalogue, but the token expires either after 23 hours or 3 months, depending on your needs for it.
Here's the thing: it's rather complicated and laborious for a non-dev or non-tech people in general to get it because you have to be registered as a developer on Meta and navigate to Graph API so you can generate the token (and so on, they will have to get it anyways to access their catalogue).
While I was reading Graph API docs, I found out that the access token is a develop test access token and not an ordinary daily access token, which gave me some hope, but unfortunately, I didn't found much info about how the catalogue access works.
I don't know if I made myself clear, but I appreciate anyone who can help me and suggest whatever I should do next!


I might be completely wrong but I think page access token is used to avoid token expiration but In catalog if Graph API is not been used in 60 days then you need to generate the login again.
Ref:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived/
